# update query in MYSQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I execute below update query in mysql workbench It will update only 2 rows.

```
UPDATE usertoken 
  SET StatusName='Completed',Id=null  
  WHERE (UserId=45 and BuddyId=46) OR (UserId=46 and BuddyId=45);
```

but the same query inside the Stored Procedure updates the entire table.

Even I hard coded the user id's inside the Stored procedure nothing changed.

Any Idea's?

UPDATE:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SubmitResult`(IN userId int,IN buddyID int,IN startTime DATETIME,IN endtime DATETIME,IN questions varchar(255),IN answers varchar(255))
BEGIN
SET @userId = userId;
SET @questions = questions;
SET @answers = answers;
SET @buddyID = buddyID;


SELECT @QuizId := QuizId from usertoken where (UserId=@userId and BuddyId=@buddyID) OR (UserId=@buddyID and BuddyId=@userId) LIMIT 1;

IF @QuizId IS NULL THEN 

    INSERT INTO QUIZ (QuizStartTime, QuizEndTime, QuizTypeId)
    SELECT startTime,endtime,1;

    SELECT @newQId := MAX(QuizId) from QUIZ LIMIT 1;

    SELECT @userId,@buddyID,@newQId;

    /* UPDATE usertoken SET QuizStatusName='Completed',QuizId=@newQId  where (UserId=@userId and BuddyId=@buddyID) OR (UserId=@buddyID and BuddyId=@userId); */
    UPDATE usertoken SET QuizStatusName='Completed',QuizId=@newQId  where UserId=45; 
    UPDATE usertoken SET QuizStatusName='Completed',QuizId=@newQId  where UserId=46;

// Some Statements

END IF;

SET @userId = NULL;
SET @questions = NULL;
SET @answers = NULL;
SET @buddyID = NULL;
SET @startTime = NULL;
SET @endtime = NULL;
SET @QID = NULL;
SET @AID = NULL;
SET @n = NULL;
SET @newQMId = NULL;
SET @newQId = NULL;
SET @QuizId = NULL;

END
```

Comment: can you share a snippet of your procedure.your query seems fine

Comment: Two UPDATE  queries inside the SP are not the same UPDATE query that was commented out.

Comment: I tried with different update queries but unsuccessful.. update query update entire table instead of updating specific row

Comment: Any ideas? Sure, you are looking at the wrong db, wrong table, calling the wrong proc, aren't dropping then re-adding the stored proc. I can think of half a dozen scenarios

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea's friends. I posted answer for my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My update query works well after prefixing the where condition with table alias name.. Not sure why it got failed but i assume that Stored procedure IN parameter has the same userId attribute and it could be cause..

After prefixing my update query,

UPDATE usertoken t
  SET t.StatusName='Completed',t.Id=null
  WHERE (t.UserId=45 and t.BuddyId=46) OR (t.UserId=46 and t.BuddyId=45);